# count global project progress in orgmode

Tags: org-mode

As in the MWE shown below, a synthesis project was split into multiple tasks to work on individually.   I understand that the progress monitor by ratio of numbers (`[/]`), or by percentage (`[%]`) accounts for tasks pending / achieved in levels directly below the level where the indicator is set, e.g., `characterization` about all spectroscopic techniques listed, and `alcohol` turns only to state `[3/3]` because its subsections are toggled to the level of `DONE`.

How is it possible to monitor the progress globally (with `[%]`, or `[/]`), across all *elementary tasks* listed for this project, irrespective their level?  A task shall be *elementary* if not split further into other tasks; thus, `characterization` would only be a category (not to count), consisting of the elementary tasks of `NMR`, `MS`, `IR` (to count).  The progress of the MWE shown below equates to `11/17` or `65%` of the work scheduled is completed.  I aim to retain the design of the plan because the project may be achieved in collaboration only (e.g., sending samples to different departments).

```
* TODO synthesis project [33%]

** DONE preparation alcohol [3/3]
   + [X] literature search
   + [X] synthesis
   + [X] characterization [4/4]
     + [X] 1H NMR
     + [X] 13C NMR
     + [X] IR
     + [X] MS

** TODO preparation acyl chloride [2/3]
   + [X] literature search
   + [X] synthesis
   + [-] characterization [2/3]
     + [X] 1H NMR
     + [X] 13C NMR
     + [ ] MS

** TODO preparation ester [1/3]
   + [X] literature search
   + [ ] synthesis
   + [ ] characterization [0/4]
     + [ ] 1H NMR
     + [ ] 13C NMR
     + [ ] IR
     + [ ] MS
```